# How can I fix my code so it can input letters

Tags: java

So i'm just learning java and I know this issue is very stupid, this is from the book Head Frist Java. When I try to put a letter instead of a number it crashes, how do I fix that? If I want it to say "pleasse try again with a number" when letter is entered.

```
    public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int numOfGuesses = 0;
    GameHelper helper = new GameHelper();

    SimpleDotCom theDotCom = new SimpleDotCom();
    int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

    int[] locations = {randomNum, randomNum+1, randomNum+2};
    theDotCom.setLocationCells(locations);
    boolean isAlive = true;
    while (isAlive == true)
    {
        String guess = helper.getUserInput("enter a number");
        String result = theDotCom.checkYourself(guess);
        numOfGuesses++;
        if (result.equals("kill")) {
            isAlive = false;
            System.out.println("You took " + numOfGuesses + " guesses");
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
    public class GameHelper {

    private static final String alphabet = "abcdefg";
    private int gridLength = 7;
    private int gridSize = 49;
    private int [] grid = new int[gridSize];
    private int comCount = 0;


    public String getUserInput(String prompt) {
    String inputLine = null;
    System.out.print(prompt + "  ");
    try {
    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(
 new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   inputLine = is.readLine();
   if (inputLine.length() == 0 )  return null; 
 } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
 }
 return inputLine.toLowerCase();
```

}

```
public class SimpleDotCom {
int[] locationCells;
int numOfHits = 0;

public void setLocationCells(int[] locs)
{
    locationCells = locs;
}

public String checkYourself(String stringGuess) {
    int guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess);
    String result = "miss";
    for (int cell: locationCells)
    {
        if (guess == cell) {
            result = "hit";
            numOfHits++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (numOfHits == locationCells.length)
    {
        result = "kill";
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Java does not 'crash'. It throws exceptions. Read the type of the exception, the message and the stack trace/line it occurred on and you can usually solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @Patashu Thanks for the hint I think I have a better idea how to read the error msg now.

Comment: @RongNK I was hoping it can display message like " please try again with a valid number"

Comment: @user2484596 you can do that too

Comment: @Bingo I can do what? When I input a letter I got an error message and Im trying to figure out how to fix this. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "r"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at SimpleDotCom.checkYourself(SimpleDotCom.java:11)
 at Game.main(Game.java:18)

Comment: @user2484596 Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965839/re-prompting-the-user-for-data-input-with-an-if-statement

Comment: @user2484596 I meant you can call that method inside catch block - check my answer

Comment: @user414076 I see where you coming from but I haven't got that far into java yet and I have no idea what scanner does.

Comment: It is just one of *several* potential duplicates. Reprompting until you get the correct input is a very common problem, and a very common *beginner* problem, at that. Skip ahead in your book to where it talks about loops. Then where it talks about user input. Then where it talks about parsing numbers. Put those concepts together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following -

```
int guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess);
```

the parsing succeeds only if `stringGuess` contains some integer (within the range of [-2147483648 - 2147483647]. Otherwise, it fails with an exception.

To avoid that you have to make sure that `stringGuess` contains the right value.

Following is where the value comes from -

```
String guess = helper.getUserInput("enter a number");
String result = theDotCom.checkYourself(guess);
```

It's the `getUserInput()` method -

```
public String getUserInput(String prompt) {
    String inputLine = null;
    System.out.print(prompt + "  ");
    try {
        BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputLine = is.readLine();
        if (inputLine.length() == 0)
            return null; // this cannot be parsed
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
    }
    return inputLine.toLowerCase(); //this might not be an integer
}
```

And that's the part that you need to fix.

Following should do the job -

```
//...
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
while (true) { //keep reading
    try {
        inputLine = is.readLine();
        int num = Integer.parseInt(inputLine); //make sure it's an integer
        if(num > -1 && num < 10) { // if it is, and within [0-9]
            break; // stop reading
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { // if not prompt again
        System.out.println("pleasse try again with a number within [0-9]");
    }
}
return inputLine; // no to lower case, it's a number
```

You can still better it up, by say just returning an `int` form this method, instead of `String`.

Comment: Thanks that totally worked!!!!

Comment: One other question how would I change the code so it will only take integers from 0-9? So i can't put in a rediculously large number or something like 1.2?

Comment: 1.2 is not an integer so it won't parse (already handled). For 0-9, once the parsing succeeds, just check the range and break the loop only if the number is within that range. I have updated the code, check it out.

Comment: Okay I got it now, thank you so much for all your help. Java is fun to learn but it's pretty hard to get right. You are a life saver!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know if stringGuess is an integer or not, you can put `Integer.parseInt(stringGuess)` in a `try { } catch` construct. `parseInt` throws an exception if its input cannot be turned into an integer, so catch it. In the catch block, we know that it was not an integer. Otherwise it was an integer. Now do the logic you want to do (displaying a message, choosing to loop or not, etc)

(If you have not yet done exception handling, look up try and catch in Java)

Comment: I am not familer with this but I will dod some research on it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by @patashu you can use `try{ } catch() { }`

as `Integer.parseInt(argument)` throws `NumberFormatException` if the `argument` is not a number(*number in the form of string*).

and about calling your input function again if user enters letter then you can simply do it by giving that particular input method a call inside `catch` block like:

```
try{
    int guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess);
    -----
    -----
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
     System.out.println("Oooppps letter entered - try again with number ");
     /**
     now here make call to your method that takes input i.e getUserInput() in your case 
    **/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for hte help, I will try it out right now!!!